# Do Settings/Help/Feedback actions belong in the Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

Google describes the navigation drawer very well in their [design guidlines.](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) and points out that

> As the navigation drawer expands [...] The overflow menu with the standard action items for Settings and Help remains visible

Also Roman Nurik mentioned in a [post](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6PwgQPMvK1p?pid=5922016777488920242&oid=113735310430199015092) some time ago that settings/feedback/... actions do not belong in the Navigation Drawer.

However, google started to break this guidline in their material design version of their apps. At least in Hangouts, Gmail, Google Maps ans some more.

So what's the current guidlines? 
**Should I put Feedback, Settings ans  Help in the overflow menu or in the Navigation Drawer?**

[image: Android Navigation Drawer]

Comment: Good link for all who want to get started with NavigationDrawe & Material Design: https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation drawer guideline and Google+ post are written before Material design.
in majority of new Google apps these items are in navigation drawer. also in new [Material design Navigation drawer](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content) guideline these items mentioned in navigation drawer.

Comment: Good link! Thanks, so it seems that google would have to update their guidlines-section/adjust the navigation drawer section.

Answer (score 0):

Google's guideline regarding Settings location:

"When a navigation drawer is accessible from the current screen, place Settings in the drawer. Otherwise, place Settings in an action overflow menu."

http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/settings.html#settings-flow-structure